# How can I set the password for the RealVNC service?

Tags: realvnc

Just install RealVNC free edition and I can't connect when it's running as a service because there is no password set. When I run "VNC Server (User Mode)" I can connect fine. How can I set the password for the service?

Googling didn't turn up any answers. Running server on Windows 7 ultimate and client on Windows XP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in service mode, you should have a task-bar icon:

1. Right click over the task-bar icon;
2. Select "Options...";

   [image: Right Mouse Click Over VNC Icon Screen Shoot]
3. If UAC is active, select <kbd>yes</kbd>;
4. From the window presented, access the first tab "Connections";
5. Click on <kbd>Configure...</kbd>;

   [image: Options Screen Shoot]
6. Set your VNC Server password, repeat the password and press <kbd>ok</kbd>;

   [image: Set Password Screen Shoot]

You're set, you should now be able to connect to your VNC Server with the password you've just set.

---

### ENABLE / DISABLE Tray Icon

If you don't see the tray icon, you can activate it using the windows Registry editor:

1. Click "Start";
2. On the search box, type "regedit" and press <kbd>enter</kbd>;
3. On the left column, navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RealVNC\vncserver
   ```
4. On the right, you should now see a `REG_DWORD` Value named "DisableTrayIcon";
5. Right click over it and select "Modify...";
6. The value should be set to "1", replace it with "0" to show the tray icon;
7. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>, as soon as you press it, the tray icon should appear.

Comment: no tray icon when running the service- only when running the "user mode" server?

Comment: @LeeTickett I've got a tray icon in service mode, I'll check for other options.

Comment: @LeeTickett You've configured windows to run VNC as a system service?

Comment: it installed a service by default and the service is running

Comment: @LeeTickett I've just installed on another windows and it stays with a tray icon. I'll try to look into this.

Comment: @LeeTickett After some reading, I've found that the tray Icon is system dependent. Don't really know what parameters are used to define if the tray icon gets presented or not, but I've edited my answer with a way to enable it.

Comment: Similar thing I ran into -- While in Service-Mode the VNC tray icon isn't visible when you RDP into the system, unless you tell RDP to connect to the console.

Comment: Saved my bacon... thx :)

Answer (score 1):

In RDP session, tray icon of Service-Mode VNC is hidden.
So connect to your VNC Server using default VNC password and then change your authentication to your desired password.

But, What’s my (username and) password?

> VNC Server password-protects remote access out-of-the-box so your
>   computer is safe as soon as you power it on.
>
> Each time you connect, you’ll be asked to enter the remote access
>   credentials for that computer:
>
> If you have a Home subscription, enter the password you specified when
>   you installed VNC Server on that computer. If you have a Professional
>   or Enterprise subscription (or took a trial), enter the username and
>   password you normally use to log on to your user account on that
>   computer.